# tesxt file while Startup in Linux

Tags: 16.04, startup-applications

I am trying to open a text file during startup in ubuntu 16.04 . I Tried by adding the path of the file in startup applications (gnome) .But , It isn't working. How can I make it possible .

Comment: What can the system do with a text file?  If it contains code you want to run, have you made the file executable? is there a shebang to tell it how to run it? or should you wish to open it in a text editor, the command will be your desired editor with parameter only being the text file.  Sorry I'm not clear which you really want.

Comment: I just need to open the text file

Comment: Again same questions.  Open to execute it?  (is it executable? is there a #! to tell the system how to execute it), or if you want to open it with a specific program - the command is the name of the program you want opened, and the name of the text file is a parameter only for the program.  eg.  `gedit textfile.txt` will be the command to open it using `gedit`, which would be `vim ~/textfile.txt` to use vim instead & open texxtfile.txt in your $HOME folder)